# Brightcove javascript smart player api, pull video thumbs from playlist

Tags: brightcove

I am trying to figure out how to create a customized experience for viewing videos in a playlist.

I want to query brightcove with a playlist id and get back video thumbs and video ids. I then want to make the thumbs clickable and load a player.

The loading of the player I know how to do. I just don't know how to make a jsonp call to brightcove for thumbs and video ids of a given playlist.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a Brightcove javascript media api wrapper which helped a lot:

http://opensource.brightcove.com/project/javascript-mapi-wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Media API is what you want. Probably the find_playlist_by_id method. Make sure you specify thumbnailURL in the video_fields parameter.

Here is an example:

http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_playlist_by_id&playlist_id=1963943654001&video_fields=id%2Cname%2CshortDescription%2CthumbnailURL&media_delivery=http&callback=BCL.onSearchResponse&token=ZY4Ls9Hq6LCBgleGDTaFRDLWWBC8uoXQun0xEEXtlDUHBDPZBCOzbw..&

There is a API builder tool at http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/samples/find_playlist_by_id.html and documentation at http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/media/reference.html#find_playlist_by_id.